# Organize list of lists in Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Let's say a have a list of lists in [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29):

```
list_of_values = [[a, b, c], [d, e, f], [g, h, i], [j, k, l]]
```

And I want to convert automatically to independent lists like:

```
list1 = [[a, b, c],[d + g + j, e + h + k, f + i + l]]
list2 = [[d, e, f], [g + j, h + k, i + l]]
list3 = [[g, h, i], [j, k, l]]
```

Let's say I have a list of lists of integers in Python:

```
list_of_values = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

And I want to convert automatically to independent lists like:

```
list1 = [[1, 2, 3],[4 + 7 + 10, 5 + 8 + 11, 6 + 9 + l2]]
list2 = [[4, 5, 6], [7 + 10, 8 + 11, 9 + 12]]
list3 = [[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, l2]]
```

Performing the math:

```
list1 = [[1, 2, 3], [21, 24, 27]]
list2 = [[4, 5, 6], [17, 19, 21]]
list3 = [[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, l2]]
```

Comment: What does `+` mean here?

Comment: I'm with PascalvKooten , are we adding the values together, or simply adding the variables to different list positions?

Comment: Did you just edit your question during the grace period? I could swear that there was no `+` stuff in there when I wrote my answer...

Comment: ThiefMaster I did not edit my question. + Means plus (or summation) of numbers (a,b,c,e,...l)

Comment: Dear user2457899 Please take time before posting an question, at-least do not change Question after you get some answers.

Comment: Dear @GrijeshChauhan, I apologize. I did not mean to change the question, once I got answers. Now I change the question to try to clarify. Thanks for helping!!

Comment: Dear @PascalvKooten yes, we are adding values together. Thank you!

Comment: @user2457899 Dear if you use community then you should follow rules here. Never change question even if you want to add information of improve question do Like I did in your question.

Comment: Dear @markcial, I tried somethings, but I'm a novice, so I gave it a shot here. Thank you!

Comment: If you tried something post your code, you will get better hints

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, I'll try to be better next time. This was my first post, and everything is new to me. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @markcial, sounds good. I'll try to be better next time! Thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your updated Question:

Suppose you have "list of lists of strings"  like below:

```
s = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i'], ['j', 'k', 'l']]
```

Then you can use: join to concatenate:

```
>>> for i in range(len(s)):
...  [s[i], map(lambda t: ''.join(t), zip(*s[i + 1:]))]
... 
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['dgj', 'ehk', 'fil']]
[['d', 'e', 'f'], ['gj', 'hk', 'il']]
[['g', 'h', 'i'], ['j', 'k', 'l']]
[['j', 'k', 'l'], []]
```

If you don't need last line in output then just use range argument less then one of length:

```
>>> for i in range(len(s)-1):
...  [s[i], map(''.join, zip(*s[i + 1:]))] # remove lambda function
... 
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['dgj', 'ehk', 'fil']]
[['d', 'e', 'f'], ['gj', 'hk', 'il']]
[['g', 'h', 'i'], ['j', 'k', 'l']]
```

But suppose if you have "list of lists of numbers" e.g.:

```
l = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

Then you can use sum function:

```
>>> for i in range(len(l) - 1):
...  [l[i], map(sum, zip(*l[i + 1:]))]
... 
[[1, 2, 3], [21, 24, 27]]
[[4, 5, 6], [17, 19, 21]]
[[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

**Edit:**..

If you wants to make single function for both strings and number then you canmake use of `add()` operator from `operator` library.

Check `add()` function:

```
>>> from operator import add
>>> add(1, 2)
3
>>> add('1', '2')  # this is like + works
'12'
```

Now, using it make a  new `my_add()` that add all elements in a sequence, check following codes:

```
>>> def my_add(t):
...  return reduce(add, t)
... 
>>> my_add(('a', 'b'))
'ab'

>>> my_add((2, 1))
3
```

Now, write a function using `my_add()` function that will so your work:

```
def do_my_work(s):
    for i in range(len(s)-1):
        print [s[i], map(my_add, zip(*s[i + 1:]))]
```

Now, see how this works for you:

```
>>> s
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i'], ['j', 'k', 'l']]
>>> do_my_work(s)
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['dgj', 'ehk', 'fil']]
[['d', 'e', 'f'], ['gj', 'hk', 'il']]
[['g', 'h', 'i'], ['j', 'k', 'l']]
>>> l
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
>>> do_my_work(l) # so same function for str and int both! 
[[1, 2, 3], [21, 24, 27]]
[[4, 5, 6], [17, 19, 21]]
[[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

Comment: Dear @GrijeshChauhan, thank you for your answer it seems to be doing the exact job I'm looking for. There are two concepts that I need to learn to fully understand your answer: map and lambda. Thanks a lot for the rapid answer!

Comment: @user2457899 Wait for some more like I am adding some more good things in answer..using `add()` just wait

Comment: @user2457899 I removed lambda. you need to learn map(), filter(), reduce().

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> lst = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i'], ['j', 'k', 'l']]
>>> for i, item in enumerate(lst):
        print [item, itertools.chain.from_iterable(lst[i+1:])]

[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l']]
[['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l']]
[['g', 'h', 'i'], ['j', 'k', 'l']]
[['j', 'k', 'l'], []]
```

Comment: `chain` is the right tool here. In this case, however, I think `chain.from_iterable` is nicer than argument unpacking.

Comment: @devnull: I usually do. But python iterator fun is one of the cases where I still enjoy figuring out a nice way to do this kind of stuff (although this one was pretty easy).

Comment: This is **not answer** where is `d + g + j` ??

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan The question changed within seconds!

Comment: Uhh??  question is 8 min old? answer is 4 min old?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Changed within the 5-min grace period (I guess).  The other answer is also similar!

Comment: user2457899 changed the question quite late, I have also seen this. Whatever, (s)he will figure out that (s)he is just a tiny `sum()` away from what (s)he wants.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan When I first saw the question `d + g + j` was not there at all :)

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in range(len(list_of_values) - 1):
    print [list_of_values[i]] + [map(list, zip(*list_of_values[i+1:]))]
```

**Output**

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], [['d', 'g', 'j'], ['e', 'h', 'k'], ['f', 'i', 'l']]]
[['d', 'e', 'f'], [['g', 'j'], ['h', 'k'], ['i', 'l']]]
[['g', 'h', 'i'], [['j'], ['k'], ['l']]]
```

For the numbers, you can simply do

```
list_of_values = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
for i in range(len(list_of_values) - 1):
    print [list_of_values[i]] + [map(sum, zip(*list_of_values[i+1:]))]
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 2, 3], [21, 24, 27]]
[[4, 5, 6], [17, 19, 21]]
[[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```